# syntax for json in mysqli

Tags: mysql, json

I want to alter my table to add a json object column, then I want to insert rows that include the json object.

I have this code for the alter but it causes a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE Product
ADD shops JSON_OBJECT NOT NULL
```

What syntax do I use to add the json object column and to insert values into it?

Comment: Have you read [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)?

Comment: Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` What version of MySQL are you using? [You need at least version 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) to utilize the [JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: @Keeleon `innodb_version
5.5.42
protocol_version
10
slave_type_conversions
version
5.5.42
version_comment
Source distribution
version_compile_machine
i386
version_compile_os
osx10.6`

Comment: @Keeleon i guess my version is 5.5.42 and I need at least 5.7.8. Thanks. I use the MAMP stack. Hopefully it is easy to update the mySql in that package

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)
`ALTER TABLE Product ADD shops JSON NOT NULL`